# Bulk Update in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I pull a bunch of timesheet entries out of the database and use them to create an invoice. Once I save the invoice and have an Id I want to update the timesheet entries with the invoice Id. Is there a way to bulk update the entities without loading them one at a time?

```
void SaveInvoice(Invoice invoice, int[] timeEntryIds) {
    context.Invoices.Add(invoice);
    context.SaveChanges();

    // Is there anything like?
    context.TimeEntries
        .Where(te => timeEntryIds.Contains(te.Id))
        .Update(te => te.InvoiceId = invoice.Id);
}
```

Comment: There is a library for this: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `TimeEntry` has an association to `Invoice` (check the navigation properties), you can probably do something like this:

```
var timeEntries = context.TimeEntries.Where(t => timeEntryIds.Contains(te.Id)).ToArray();

foreach(var timeEntry in timeEntries)
    invoice.TimeEntries.Add(timeEntry);

context.Invoices.Add(invoice);

//save the entire context and takes care of the ids
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Instead of doing this I added the TimeEntries to the invoice before I saved it. invoice.TimeEntries = context.TimeEntries.Where(te => timeEntryIds.Contains(te.Id)).ToArray()

Answer (score 18):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Our library has a Batch Update feature which I believe is what you are looking for

This feature supports EF Core

```
// Is there anything like? YES!!!
context.TimeEntries
    .Where(te => timeEntryIds.Contains(te.Id))
    .Update(te => new TimeEntry() { InvoiceId = invoice.Id });
```

Wiki: [EF Batch Update](http://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update)

**EDIT:** Answer comment

> does it supports contains as in your example? I think this is coming from EF Core which is not supported feature in 3.1 version even

EF Core 3.x support contains: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DAdIO2

**EDIT:** Answer comment

> this is great but this requires to have zero parameter public constructors for classes. which is not a great. Any way to get around this issue?

Anonymous type is supported starting from EF Core 3.x

```
context.TimeEntries
    .Where(te => timeEntryIds.Contains(te.Id))
    .Update(te => new { InvoiceId = invoice.Id });
```

Online example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MAnPvw

Comment: this is great but this requires to have zero parameter public constructors for classes. which is not a great. Any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 18):

As of EFCore 7.0 you will see the built-in `BulkUpdate()` and `BulkDelete` methods:

```
   context.Customers.Where(...).ExecuteDelete();
   context.Customers.Where(...).ExecuteUpdate(c => new Customer { Age = c.Age + 1 });
   context.Customers.Where(...).ExecuteUpdate(c => new { Age = c.Age + 1 });
   context.Customers.Where(...).ExecuteUpdate(c => c.SetProperty(b => b.Age, b => b.Age + 1));
```

Comment: A note to anyone who finds this - EFCore 7 isnt released yet and is expected to be released November 2022.

Comment: the API is ExecuteDelete()/ExecuteUpdate()  in the final release version.

Comment: ExecuteDelete()/ExecuteUpdate() are not working with `InMemory` Please check this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74907256/ef-7-new-executedelete-and-executeupdate-methods-not-working-on-an-in-memory-d

Answer (score 8):

Are you after the performance of simplified syntax?

I would suggest to use direct SQL query,

```
 string query = "Update TimeEntries Set InvoiceId = <invoiceId> Where Id in (comma separated ids)";    
 context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(query);
```

For comma separated ids you can do `string.Join(',', timeEntryIds)`

It depends on what you actually need. If you want to go with Linq, then you need to iterate through each object.

Comment: SQL Injection Attack !! Everybody using EF knows that they can fire SQL but it is not recommended.

Comment: Microsofts own EF documentation recommends raw sql inserts for bulk updating for efficiency: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating

Answer (score 4):

The [`IQueryable.ToQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-5.0) method introduced in Entity Framework Core 5.0 may help with this scenario. This method will generate SQL that can be included in a raw SQL query to perform a bulk update of records identified by that query.

For example:

```
void SaveInvoice(Invoice invoice, int[] timeEntryIds) {
    context.Invoices.Add(invoice);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var query = context.TimeEntries
        .Where(te => timeEntryIds.Contains(te.Id))
        .Select(te => te.Id);

    var sql = $"UPDATE TimeEntries SET InvoiceId = {{0}} WHERE Id IN ({query.ToQueryString()})";

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, invoice.Id);
}
```

The major drawback of this approach is that you end up with raw SQL appearing in your code. However I don't know of any reasonable way to avoid that with current Entity Framework Core capabilities - you're stuck with this caveat, or the caveats of other answers posted here such as:

- Introducing a dependency on another library such as [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/) or [ELinq](https://try.entitylinq.com/).
- Using `DbContext.SaveChanges()` which will involve the execution of multiple SQL queries to retrieve and update records one at a time rather than doing a bulk update.

Answer (score 4):

Bulk update supported with EF 7:

```
context
.TimeEntries
.Where(te => timeEntryIds.Contains(te.Id))
.ExecuteUpdate(s => s.SetProperty(
    i => te.InvoiceId,
    i => invoice.Id));
```

Also there is async version for this method ExecuteUpdateAsync.

Answer (score 2):

In entity framework core , you can do with [update range method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.updaterange?view=efcore-2.1). you can see some samples usage [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/update-data-in-entity-framework-core.aspx) .

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
     context.UpdateRange(yourModifiedEntities);

     // or the followings are also valid
     //context.UpdateRange(yourModifiedEntity1, yourModifiedEntity2, yourModifiedEntity3);
    //context.YourEntity.UpdateRange(yourModifiedEntities);
    //context.YourEntity.UpdateRange(yourModifiedEntity1, yourModifiedEntity2,yourModifiedEntity3);

    context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Be aware that while EF improves performance by executing an UPDATE statement per entity, it doesn't run a single UPDATE statement that updates all entities at once, like @Dhanuka777's example above. The latter is much, much faster.

Comment: @SandorDrieënhuizen I don't understand how executing an UPDATE statement per entity is faster than a single UPDATE. So you say running update 10.000 times is faster than running it once? Come on.

Comment: @schlingel: Even though you're only calling a single `UpdateRange` command, EF generates an SQL UPDATE statement for each entity under the hood. Thus, you're still effectively doing lots of separate update queries which is much slower than a single combined UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1):

in EF Core 7, use ExecuteUpdate(), [what's new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates)

```
var multipleRows = TableA.Where(t=>t.Id < 99);

multipleRows.ExecuteUpdate(t=> 
    t.SetProperty(
        r => r.Salary,
        r => r.Salary * 2));
    
//SQL already sent to database, do not run below
//SaveChanges();
```

SQL being generated by EF

```
UPDATE [t]
SET [t].[Salary] = [t].[Salary] * 2
FROM [TableA] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[ID] < 99
```