# Is There A More Efficient Way To Code This Entity Framework Core UpdateRange Code?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, bulkupdate

```
var results = context.Customer.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerId).AsQueryable();

foreach(Customer cust in results)
{
    cust.isDeleted = true;
}

context.UpdateRange(results);
context.SaveChanges();
```

** Using the loop seems inefficient. Can the fetch and update be done in a single statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk Update in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531602/bulk-update-in-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 1):

If you want better performance, execute SQL instead:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"UPDATE Customer SET isDeleted = 1 WHERE CustomerId = {customerId}");
```

EF Core will protect from injection and generate a SQL parameter for you.

EDIT:
As Peter has pointed out in the comments, keep in mind that this will cause any entities already loaded to be out of sync with the database.

Comment: A note should probably be added that if any of these records had already been loaded into the DbContext, then after this they will have an outdated value in their `isDeleted` properties.