# Http post and put as IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webapi

I am new to stackoverflow. I would like to know how can I add and Edit products

for example

```
     [HttpPost("api/products")]
     public ActionResult <IEnumerable<Product>> CreateProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
     {
      //    Note: I am getting product as collection
      //    I am using ef core. and would like to add all products
     }
    
    
    [HttpPut("api/products")]
    public ActionResult <IEnumerable<Product>> updateProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
    //      Note: I am getting product as collection
    //      I am using ef core. and would like to edit all products
    }

    class  Product
    {
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public string Price {get;set;}
    }
```

any advice. I have done google and found many example that add or edit product as single object but not as collection

Regards

Comment: Take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531602/bulk-update-in-entity-framework-core

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this (bear in mind this is just for giving you an idea, no doubt there is a better way)

```
    [HttpPut("api/products")]
    public ActionResult <IEnumerable<Product>> updateProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
     foreach(var product in products)
      {
         var propuctInDb=_dbContext.Products.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id==product.Id);
          productInDb.Name=product.Name;
        productInDb.Price=product.Price;
       }
  _dbContext.SaveChanges();
  }
```

> Do not call SaveChanges() in each loop.