# EF 7 - new ExecuteDelete and ExecuteUpdate methods not working on an in-memory database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I'm using the new EF 7 `ExecuteDelete` and `ExecuteUpdate` features and they are great. But when I try to write unit test for the functions that use them, these tests crash.

I'm using EF 7.0.1 on .NET Core 7, `Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.InMemory` 7.0.1, and Xunit 2.4.2

```
[Fact]
public async Task DeleteAccountAsync__Success()
{
    var accountId = Guid.Parse("52ff9d4e-efb9-4b51-b5e7-1734d10187f7");

    // CRASH
    _context.Accounts
            .Where(p => p.AccountId == accountId)
            .ExecuteDelete();
}

private void SeedDataBase()
{
    var a1 = new Account
        {
            AccountId = Guid.Parse("52ff9d4e-efb9-4b51-b5e7-1734d10187f7"),
        };

    var a2 = new Account
        {
            AccountId = Guid.Parse("d5c38300-0de6-4118-8d01-6bc94842d4b5"),
        };

    _context.Accounts.AddRange(a1, a2);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is the error I get:

> Message   "The LINQ expression 'DbSet()\n    .Where(a => a.AccountId == __accountId_0)\n    .ExecuteDelete()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Using EF in memory provider for testing is usually not a good idea. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli. "While some users use the in-memory database for testing, this is generally discouraged; the SQLite provider in in-memory mode is a more appropriate test replacement for relational databases"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These new extensions only work on relational providers. And InMemory is not a relational provider

Answer (score 1):

Even when using sqlite, ExecuteUpdate is not working in EF.Core.Sqlite 7.02.  ExecuteDelete works and ExecuteUpdate throws no errors, but it doesn't actually update records.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33718039)